# Loop program with commands to other programs

Tags: r

I have these lines of code in one program:

```
source("R:/ML NC8 MENSAL.R")

source("R:/ ML NPC NC8 MENSAL.R")
```

The mentioned programs both have these lines of code:

```
# Defining Variable

MONTH <- "01_2021"
```

I want to make this definition in the first program for the two programs.

Which code should I write?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It might be some work, but it can be useful to have each script, or "program" return a function (or a set of functions), not actually run lines of code. You can then pass in variables and call the functions to run what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If both scripts have these lines and you only want to return it from the first script, then I would write a function in both scripts. Only the first one would return the month-value.

```
month_return_scr1 <- function(){
MONTH <- "01_2021"
#more code
return(list(MONTH, more variables, or data.frames)}
month_return_scr2 <- function(){
MONTH <- "01_2021"
#more code
return(list(more variables, or data.frames)}
```

The Month would then not be returned by the second source.

Comment: Can you share the code in two parts - the one for the first program ande the one for the second program? Thank You.

Comment: The script taht will return the month: 
month_return_scr1 <- function(){
MONTH <- "01_2021"
#more code
return(list(MONTH, more variables, or data.frames)}
The script that will return other things, but not the month:  month_return_scr2 <- function(){
MONTH <- "01_2021"
#more code
return(list(more variables, or data.frames)}

Answer (score 0):

I used successfully the following solution:

1. Create a program - R:/constants.R - with the month variable (and any
   others used in all programs)
2. Create a program - R:/superprogram.R - that executes all the 23 programs
3. In each 23 programs replace the variables definition for this code
   source("R:/constants.R"). This will bring the constants defined in
   the source file into the global environment.
4. Change the variables in program R:/constants.R and save it
5. Run R:/superprogram.R